# Trying to count the number of matching items in a table column

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, countif

I am trying to determine the number of items in a column that match a specific string.  I want to be able to use this number to size an array later.

I have been trying various ways to use the countif function.

```
Sub testMatrix()

Dim nm1 As String
Dim nm2 As String
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim nm1Count As Double
Dim nm2Count As Integer

nm1 = "teleport 1"
nm2 = "user2"

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObject("Table1")

nm1Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Table1[username]"), nm1)

End Sub
```

I would like to end up with the variable `nm1Count` being equal to the number of times string "teleport 1" occurs in the `username` column of my table.  So for my specific sheet it should say 4.

Currently, when it gets to the `nm1Count = line` it errors out and says

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dumbly forgot the s at the end of ListObjects.  Here is the corrected code.

```
Sub testMatrix()

Dim nm1 As String
Dim nm2 As String
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim nm1Count As Long
Dim nm2Count As Long

nm1 = "teleport 1"
nm2 = "user2"

ActiveSheet.Activate

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

nm1Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), nm1)
nm2Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), nm2)




End Sub
```